# How to define a function in one linux kernel module and use it in another?

Tags: linux-kernel

I developed two simple modules to the kernel. Now i want to define a function in one module and after that use it in the other.

How i can do that?

Just define the function  and caller in the other module without problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call exported kernel module functions from another module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311867/how-to-call-exported-kernel-module-functions-from-another-module)

Answer (score 35):

Define it in `module1.c`:

```
#include <linux/module.h>

int fun(void);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(fun);

int fun(void)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

And use it in `module2.c`:

```
extern int fun(void);
```

Comment: I still have a problem. In the directory /var/log/ i open the file messages to see the printk done buy my function. Appears a message like this :" module license "unspecified" taints kernel","Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint". I just call the function of one module to print a message in the other module.

Comment: @Ricardo: That's not related to exporting functions, but simply to the fact, that you didn't define the module's license. Use the `MODULE_LICENSE` macro to do that.

Comment: Is working. Thank you. For modules inside the kernel image, is the same process?

Comment: What happens if you are adding these modules to a Linux kernel and you set both of them to compile as modules? When trying `make`, the kernel will not compile, because it cannot resolve the reference to foo() in module2.c, right? How could it be solved? @JanHudec

Comment: @marcocamejo: You need to specify that module2 depends on module1, but I don't know the exact details.

Comment: I can't seem to insmod module2.ko.
Am I missing something?

Comment: @cnicutar: I think the declration in the `module2.c` should be `extern int fun(void);` instead of `foo`.