# Linux Kernel module calling a function in another module

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Is it possible for a function in a linux kernel module calling a function in another module ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820458/kernel-modules-develop/9820518#9820518

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call exported kernel module functions from another module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311867/how-to-call-exported-kernel-module-functions-from-another-module)

Comment: I wonder why no one else mentioned this. EXPORT_SYMBOL and extern <prototype> is not enough. In the Kbuild file of the module that is importing symbol, add a line KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS = <path-to-exporting-module>/Module.symvers . This helps the importing module know what symbols will be imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Of course, the other kernel module must be loaded.

For an example, look at the USB code, which is implemented as a mullti-layer driver, with each layer in its own module.Reference link [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x437.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using `EXPORT_SYMBOL` in Linux.

If one module has one function called `etx_shared_func` and one global variable called `etx_count`. This function and variable can be shared among with all the loadable modules using `EXPORT_SYMBOL`.

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(etx_shared_func);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(etx_count);
```